# Maven Release Plugin - Multi Module Project - release:prepare - Why I see SKIPPED for child modules though BUILD IS SUCCESSFUL

Tags: maven-release-plugin

Good Morning.

I am using maven release-plugin in a MultiModule Project.

Though `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform` are SUCCESSFUL why do I see "SKIPPED" for child maven modules when I run `mvn release:prepare`.

Please help me.

My codebase folder structure is as follows:

```
 PARENT 
##############
c:\projects\MavenRightMultiModuleParent\pom.xml

c:\projects\MavenRightMultiModuleParent\src\main\java

c:\projects\MavenRightMultiModuleParent\src\test\java

Parent POM.xml have below as <MODULES><MODULEchild1webapp></MODULE>......</MODULES>

 CHILD MODULES 
###################

c:\projects\MavenRightMultiModuleParent\child1webapp\pom.xml
.....


c:\projects\MavenRightMultiModuleParent\child2webapp\pom.xml
......


    [INFO] Cleaning up after release...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] MavenRightMultiModuleParent ....................... SUCCESS [16.766s]
    [INFO] child1webapp Maven Webapp ......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] child2webapp ...................................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 17.911s
    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 25 00:38:58 EST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Is correct.

If the children have not put the tag "version" does not need to be updated.

The end result is correct.

Comment: I have the same problem, but all my colleges have ability to do "mvn release:prepare" , but I does not wok for me :(.

Please extend your answer if possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can not update the children if you put the tag "version" within the "parent", if you want to update the child, enter the version number of the parent as follows:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X</version>
</parent>
```

thus, incorporating the property "-DautoVersionSubmodules=true", ex: "mvn -B release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules=true", automatically update all calls of the children to the "parent"